# Live Sorting by Custom Field in Wordpress

Tags: wordpress, sorting

Im working on a wordpress powered website for a client that involves a directory of local offices. Part of their requirement is that live sorting be implemented via drop downs, so when someone selects X Office in X Area, the page dynamically loads the relevant results.

I currently have a custom post type set-up called "listing", which lists all the relevant information for that office. I then display each of those fields via the Loop.

In a perfect world, a plugin would exist that would perform the above, but I've yet to find one. The closest I've come is The custom category sorting over at Digging into Wordpress.

Any suggestions on a "easy" solution that would allow me to sort "listings" with multiple attributes?

Answer (score 1):

please use the wp-smart-sort plugin for that.
With the help of this plugin you can also sort the custom field
If there is any issue after the use of this plugin then let me know
thanks